# MyBatis return both emptyList() and null

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Here is my myBatis request which should return a List:

```
@Mapper
public interface ClientAccessMapper {
    List<ClientAccess> findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal(@Param("clientId") Long clientId,
                                                             @Param("partner") String partner,
                                                             @Param("autoRenewal") Boolean autoRenewal);
}

<select id="findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal" resultMap="ClientAccessResult">
        select * from client_access
        where client_id = #{clientId}
            and partner = #{partner}
        <if test="autoRenewal != null">
            and auto_renewal = #{autoRenewal}
        </if>
        order by id
    </select>
```

Sometimes the request returns "null" instead of an empty List.
After getting I have a checking block:

```
final List<ClientAccess> clientAccesses = clientAccessMapper.findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal(client, partner, true);
        if (clientAccesses.isEmpty()) {/**/}
```

and my `clientAccesses.isEmpty()` SOMETIMES produces NPE because of null instead of a List with size = 0.
What can be a problem?

Comment: isEmpty() should be gaurded by null check

Comment: @bananas I see, but my question is about producing a result of the request. I'm trying to understand the framework's working

Comment: `I'm trying to understand the framework's working` is another concern. Use docs

Comment: I would recommend looking at `findByClientAndPartnerWithAutoRenewal` implementation

Comment: @МаксимРыбалкин MyBatis does not return `null` with that mapper. There must be something else (a plugin, for example) changing the result. Try setting a breakpoint on `org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(String, Object, RowBounds, ResultHandler)` and see what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible null pointer.
Recommended use:

```
CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceList)
```

Comment: Though this solution can work, it seems there's something else wrong in the way the OP is calling the engine. This workaround shouldn't be necessary.